# docker mounted volume data getting wiped after restart the server

Tags: docker, kong

I am trying with docker. I ran kong docker Image and linked it with cassandra database which is mounted to the folder /data/api. but whenever I restart the server I am not able to see the mounted volume and all the data in the db lost.

here is the command which i am using

```
docker run -d --name kong-database -p 9042:9042 -v /data/api:/var/lib/cassandra cassandra:2.2
```

after i run db docker image I am running kong

```
docker run --privileged -d --name kong  --link kong-database:kong-database -e "KONG_DATABASE=cassandra" -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" -e 
"KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" -p 80:8000 -p 443:8443 -p 7001:7001 -p 7946:7946 -p 7946:7946/udp kong
```

my kong entries are there mounted to the folder /data/api. but when I restarted my servercouldn't see the folder /data/api

because of this reason I am stuck at my work. can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is cassandra configured to use /var/lib/cassandra?

Comment: What is your OS? for RHEL/CentOS you maybe have to perform `chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /my/own/datadir`

Comment: + can you explain your issue a bit more? did you restart your server? Than your containers will stop running or you have to provide the `--restart always` flag.

Comment: @Robert, yes I configured cassandra /var/lib/cassandra

Comment: @lorenzvth7,
I am using Rancher OS. Yes I did restart. and I didn't enable the flag --restart always.

Comment: @Nimms Your container will only restart after a reboot when you define that flag in your `docker run` command

Comment: Hi All any hope on this question?

Comment: Did you try to start your container with docker run xxx --restart=always and reboot after that?

Comment: No, let me try this